# Archiving application

Tags: backup

I am looking for an application that takes files which will not change over time (photos, scanned pdf documents like tax returns or work records) and archives them across multi storage media types: multiple cloud services, ftp uploads, local disk, and dvd backup. This way in case the house burns down and my cloud account is full I might still be able to access my files. It would be helpful if it showed which files were redundantly stored where.

I would also like the program to manage which files were archived (as in I don't want to have to think about the task of archiving specific sub folders).

Essentially, an automated version of the Scott Hanselman blog post:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheComputerBackupRuleOfThree.aspx

Any ideas? Overkill? Thanks!

Comment: Is this program supposed to detect and select the files automatically, or more like you select them and place them somewhere and the program handles the backup automatically?

Comment: Ideally, you would add the files along with some meta info like a tag or person or category of document.  The application would store files locally and compress them before marking them for a backup to DVD or removable media or a cloud storage account.  Since you don't delete the files or change them it can be incremental... As in the app would know what has been burned or uploaded so you don't have to keep tabs on  that yourself.  I was thinking of writing something myself or cobbeling together a solution but I wanted to make sure it wasn't already done.

Comment: In a more direct answer to your question: the latter option of selecting and the app does backup.